# Is there a general name for $(a\star b)$, $\star$ being any arbitrary ( binary) operation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, soft-question, terminology, arithmetic

$\bullet$ We have a name for the image of $( a, b)$ under the operation of addition, namely a *sum*.

$\bullet$ We have a name for the image of $( a, b)$ under the operation of multiplication , namely a *product*.

$\bullet$ We have other names such as *quotient*, or *difference* for other operations.

It seems that it would be useful to have a name denoting in general the image of an arbitrary ordered pair $(a,b)$ under an arbitrary operation $\star$.

Is there such a name?

Comment: I feel like more often than not, the word "product" is used, especially in group theory.

Comment: I agree with Nick. "Product" is very frequently used in an abstract setting (even when there is no connection to multiplication of numbers). I have sometimes seen "composition" (even when there is no connection to composition of functions).

Comment: It can be refered to as the “compositum” (or, ungrammatically, as the “composite”). But it almost never is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no universally understood term which will denote the result of applying a binary operation to two objects.  As such, if you decide to use such a term, you should be careful to define that term before you start using it willy-nilly.  That being said, there seem to be several options, include those mentioned in the comments.  I am presenting them is the order that, in my opinion, runs from worst to best (that is, the best options are at the bottom).

- **Sum:** The object $a \star b$ is the *sum* of $a$ and $b$.  In general, I would say that calling it a sum implies that $\star$ is a commutative operation.  If it is not commutative, then "sum" may be inappropriate.
- **Composite:** The object $a\star b$ is the *composition* or *composite* of $a$ and $b$.  In my experience, function composition is often the "multiplicative operation" of an [algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field).  For example, multiplication of two $n\times n$ matrices can be seen as the composition of the two linear transformations represented by those matrices—this notion generalizes nicely to spaces of linear functionals (for example).  Personally, I would think that "composition" implies **non**commutativity, but I can't back that up with anything other than my own gut.
- **Product:** The object $a \star b$ is the *product* of $a$ and $b$.  This is likely to be an easily understood term—an arbitrary binary operation can often be understood as a generalized version of addition or multiplication.  As noted above, "sum" implies commutativity, while "product" does not (though multiplication *can be* commutative, so there is no loss of generality).
- **Result:**  The object $a\star b$ is the *result of starring* $a$ and $b$.  That is, come up with a noun to describe the operation (this is the "star operation"), verb that noun, then use the phrase suggested above.
- **Image:** [See J.G.'s answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3632192/468350)
- **$\star$-product:**  Finally, saving the best for last, call $a\star b$ the *$\star$-product* of $a$ and $b$.  Read aloud, if $c = a\star b$, then say

  > $c$ is the star-product of $a$ and $b$.

  I think that this is likely to be completely unambiguous, and offers the most bang for the buck.

Answer (score 1):

A binary operator can be construed as a binary function we just like to write without the usual $f(a,\,b)$ notation. Then $a\star b$ is an *image* of the operator/function.

As others have noted, in certain contexts *product* is also used. (Presumably, it won out over *sum* because "addition" is usually reserved for a commutative operation, [with one obvious exception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Addition)).

Answer (score 0):

$a*b$ is in fact a simple example of a "word".  But generally it would be called the product of $a$ and $b$.